# Extjs4.1 Grid- How to get cellIndex in itemdblclick function

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I using grid panel and listener like

```
listeners: {
   ,itemdblclick: function (grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
        // how to get cellIndex
   }
}
```

I try to get celIndex but nothing. How to get cellIndex in itemdblclick function thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`celldblclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-celldblclick) event instead of `itemdblclick`.

```
listeners: {
   celldblclick: function (table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {

   }
}
```